# Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to create year to use in date from a number of columns, getting number with trailing zeros.
I use the calculation below to calculate year,

```
f2.loc[:,'frt_elig_year'] = (f2['FrstElAge']-f2['iss_age']) + f2['eff_date'].dt.year
```

Get the year but with `4 0's` after i.e. `2021.0000`

checked the

```
type('first_elig_year')
str
```

however when I try to remove using:

```
f2.loc[:,'frt_elig_year']= f2['frt_elig_year'].str[:4]
```

I get message:

```
Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas
```

Comment: `'first_elig_year'` is a string. Of course `type('first_elig_year')` is `str`. You should try `f2['first_elig_year'].dtype`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try

```
f2['frt_elig_year']=f2['frt_elig_year'].astype('str')
```

before making the substring .str[:4]

you can check the types of the variables of the dataframe by using

```
f2.dtypes
```

Comment: it acutally is a float 64

Comment: then you should use the .astype('str') before you're able to use the .str[:4]

Comment: Thanks a million that worked: Tried turning into date now with 2 other columns :f2[:,'test_date'] = pd.to_datetime(f2[['fst_elig_year','po_eff_date_mth','po_eff_date_day']])   now get message :ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing

Comment: Great! Remember to mark it as ‘answered’ please!  What error is throwing the date conversion?

Comment: f2.loc[:,'po_eff_date_mth'] = f2['po_eff_date'].dt.month
f2.loc[:,'po_eff_date_day'] = f2['po_eff_date'].dt.day are the the other two varaibles in test_date